# Remove various data from log keeping specific IPs

Tags: sorting, sed, grep, unique

I've been trying to whittle down a firewall log to get a range of IPs attempting to connect through a specific port and I'm currently stuck on how to finish this out. I started out with whats below but like 65Gb worth of it (in a single file).

```
2015-11-30T08:03:03.830844-07:00 192.x.x.x %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 13 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 19 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 11881
2015-11-30T08:03:15.886962-07:00 192.x.x.x %ASA-4-405001: Received ARP request collision from 192.x.x.x/x.x.x on interface inside with existing ARP entry 192.x.x.x/x.x.x
2015-11-30T08:03:23.903154-07:00 192.x.x.x %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 8 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 20 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 12034
2015-11-30T08:03:25.595748-07:00 192.x.x.x %ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src outside:17.155.127.223/16387 dst inside:8.x.x.x/xxx by access-group "outside_access_in" [0x0, 0x0]
```

Eventually through some grep commands and *cough* archaic find and replace in notepadd++ got it down to whats below in multiple files

```
 17.155.127.223/16387 dst inside:8.x.x.x/xxx 
 17.155.127.223/16387 dst inside:8.x.x.x/xxx 
 17.173.255.223/16387 dst inside:8.x.x.x/xxx 
 17.173.255.223/16387 dst inside:8.x.x.x/xxx
```

Not exact matches to the above but it shows I was able to remove the timestamps and only retain the events that were on port /16387 now I am stuck trying to remove everything after the port while keeping the IP they originated from, that being removing the "dst inide:8.x.x.x/xxxx"

I tried to use whats below but it doesn't make any changes in my output file.

```
sed -e "s/16387.*$/-16387/p" FILE > OUTPUTFILE
```

So that is my first problem.

To explain something that I think (I'm incredibly new to this) isn't normal for Unix commands(syntax?), the " instead of ' is because I'm on Windows running Unix commands with the help of **UnxUtls**. At least I think thats why, tried the commands with ' but wouldn't work until I replaced with "

My second problem is attempting to look through a file and simply send unique lines to a file. I've tried to sort with the below command but for some reason the sort I got through UnxUtls will NOT work on my system, some temp directory error, most likely caused by some problem with UnxUtls. Is there another way to sort out unique lines?

```
sort FILE | uniq > OUTPUTFILE
```

To better explain, going from

```
 17.155.127.223/16387
 17.155.127.223/16387
 17.173.255.223/16387
 17.173.255.223/16387
```

to

```
17.155.127.223/16387
17.173.255.223/16387
```

I searched and searched but can't figure out these last two parts. Although most of what I was able to accomplish was from different posts here. Apologies if this is too long or not easily understood.

Comment: your `sort |uniq` try should work for your `To better explain..`  example, right?

Comment: This looks very much like a problem with a knock-off set of tools.  The things you describe ''should work''.

Comment: It should from what I understand yes, but for some reason the sort command from UnxUtls does not want to work properly, some error about temp directory. Googling the error doesn't give me a fix that worked but from what @sycamorex posted I think i'll be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have better luck with Cygwin on Windows. You can achieve both things with the following:

```
 ~/tmp
$ cat text.txt
17.155.127.223/16387 dst inside:8.x.x.x/xxx
17.155.127.223/16387 dst inside:8.x.x.x/xxx
17.173.255.223/16387 dst inside:8.x.x.x/xxx
17.173.255.223/16387 dst inside:8.x.x.x/xxx


$ awk '{print $1}' text.txt | uniq
17.155.127.223/16387
17.173.255.223/16387
```

The awk command will print column number 1. This will be piped to uniq which will remove duplicate lines. You can also use the `sort` command to sort it.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. Also thanks for the suggestion on Cygwin, seems better than what I was using.